# SAML encrypted assertions vs encrypted attributes

Tags: encryption, saml

When using encryption for SAML SSO, I can see a `<saml2:EncryptedAssertion>` in a use-case where encryption is working as expected.

However, for another use-case, the encrypted payload is different. There is a `<saml:AttributeStatement>` under `<saml:Assertion>` which contains `<saml:EncryptedAttribute>` sub-items in the attrib statement.

Is the 2nd example a valid encrypted payload? I'm having trouble decrypting the assertion with encrypted attributes, want to make sure that this should be a standard / supported format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you do not want to encrypt the whole SAML Assertion it's also fine to only encrypt Attributes (and/or the NameID). Please see section 2.7.3.2 of [SAMLv2 Core specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf)